# Form Data Request using NSURLConnection in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I want to make http form post using NSURLConnection in iOS. I have two form fields and one file upload option in an HTML form. When I am doing same thing using `NSURLConnection` I am not getting a response.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://url/test.php";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"myphoto.png\"rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-streamrnrn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:filedata];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&s=YL4e6ouKirNDgCk0xV2HKixt&hw=141246514ytdjadh"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"RETURNED:%@",returnString);
```

But when I use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) and write the following code it's working and I am getting a response.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/test.php"]];
[request setPostValue:@"YL4e6ouKirNDgCk0xV2HKixt&hw" forKey:@"ssf"];
[request setPostValue:@"141246514ytdjadh" forKey:@"sds"];
[request setData:filedata withFileName:@"myphoto.png" andContentType:@"image/jpeg"  forKey:@"file"];
[request startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"response:%@",response);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with the `NSURLConnection` part?

Comment: @dbrajkovic can you suggest me if I am doing anything wrong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not copying the example of that link. In that tutorial, the HTTPBody parameter is supposed to be an instance of NSData, not NSString.

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"value1=test3&value2=test"];
[request setHTTPBody:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Actually I have done mistake when writing in stack ,I edited it

Comment: I am not getting that boundary part also.

Comment: What about boundary do you not get? It's a pointer to an instance of NSString.

Comment: What's it functionality in server ?Is it required? I have to post 2 variables and one image file upload option in html form.Can u give me what will be code just request part.

Comment: The code an explanation is all in that tutorial. Do you need me to retype it here? If you can't understand what's going on, I think you should learn a little more about the concepts behind what you're trying to do. Simply copying code is not to going to help you.

Answer (score 8):

I tried this code for uploading the image and its working. Added boundry.

```
NSString *urlString = @"URL";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"Test.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine for me.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:///URL/iinsert.php"]];

    NSString *myreqstr=@"name=abhii&address=knrr";
    NSData *myreqdata=[NSData dataWithBytes:[myreqstr UTF8String] length:[myreqstr length]];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [ req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [ req setHTTPBody: myreqdata ];

    //[req setValue:@"abhii" forHTTPHeaderField:@"name"];
    //[req setValue:@"kar" forHTTPHeaderField:@"address"];
    NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
    NSString *returnstring=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",returnstring);




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ....

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSString *myRequestString =@"Request string";
NSLog(@"%@",myRequestString);
NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];

[ request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
```

Comment: I think I have done the same thing.Can you tell me what's the diffrence in code.

Answer (score 0):

You have several

```
rn
```

in the end of your strings. All of them should be

```
\r\n
```

More precisely it should be:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"myphoto.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```