# How to Upload files created in the iPad?

Tags: ios, file-upload

I am trying to go on with a project but maybe i am asking the wrong questions to google.

I have been using NSURLConnection to download files

```
NSURLRequest * XMLRequested = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kilkadg.com/cursos/images/imagenes.xml"]];

NSURLConnection * conexion = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:XMLRequested delegate:self];
```

and implement the next methods

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [imagenBytes appendData:data];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    [imagenBytes writeToFile:[DataImage imagenSource:self.name] atomically:YES];

}
```

**Now I want to do it in the other way.** I want a file created in the iPad, as a photo or a sound, save it in my server.

I haven´t find which class to use, neither how to receive that data in my server.

Thanks

Comment: You've already used the right class (NSURLConnection), make a POST instead of a GET. See the examples in the class reference. The bigger problem should be to set up the receiving server. Where do you want to upload to?

Comment: Thanks ott. I had tried that without succeed, in my server I used php. When I make a post from the browser of my computer, the file makes it´s job, but from the app, it doesn´t. Maybe I am sending in a wrong way the post data.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460817/form-data-request-using-nsurlconnection-in-ios and the `Related` in the right column.

Comment: I could not pass the code here cause I don´t get the point on how to do it, anyway I found the answer in 
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=427513 -and in- http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/#comment-8145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the creation of sound in the iPad I used http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29

To send Post data and files I used this link http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/#comment-8145

So instead of save a .png I saved a .caf