# What I did is correct or not? When I send an audio file to server in NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

I am recording audio in a `.wav` format and converting the `.wav1` file to `NSData` and sending to server.

Recorded path is:

> file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/8F81BA4C-7C6F-4496-BDA7-30C45478D758/Documents/sound.wav

I am sending to the server using:

```
audioURL=@"file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/8F81BA4C-7C6F-4496-BDA7-30C45478D758/Documents/sound.wav";


NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue: @"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSData *audiodata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];
NSMutableData *highScoreData = [NSMutableData data];
[highScoreData appendData:audiodata];
[request setHTTPBody:highScoreData];
 nsurlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request
                                                  delegate: self];
```

When I play this back it gives me the right recorded voice. However, when I play the same recorded voice from the server it says "quotation" instead of the actual recorded voice.

My full code of how I did audio recording and how i send the audio [can be found here](http://pastie.org/6410731).

Please tell me if the way I did this(i.e, to sending to server) is correct or not?

Comment: Are you sure you want to send the data as "multipart/form-data" and not as an audio file format type?   That might be affecting how the receiving system is interpreting it.

Comment: its mandatory to me to send  in bytes form.... so now, what is the right one to place ??  is it enough this  "multipart/form-data" or do we need to put any other ? @gaige

Comment: In the case of an actual multi-part form, you're going to have to create the data such that it complies with the multipart, which means creating sub-parts, naming them correctly, and putting the dividers in.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460817/form-data-request-using-nsurlconnection-in-ios answer from @Nikhil for a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Multipart requests don't work that way. You need boundaries to differ between different data. Please check: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

For the solution, I use AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).
The AFHTTPClient can create multipart requests for you.
Check: http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/multipartFormRequestWithMethod:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to upload. The header part depends on how your server handles this.
AsiFormdata is more proper here.

NSString* fileString;

```
fileString = [[self documentsPath]
              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testcombine.m4a"];

NSData* songData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileString];



NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/UsingWebServer2/UploadServlet",RemoteEndpoint]];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [request setData:songData withFileName:@"upload_test.m4a" andContentType:@"audio/m4a" forKey:@"file"];

//[request appendPostData:[Jstring  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[request startSynchronous];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send the data via multipart/form-data, use `ASIFormDataRequest`. Find documentation [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for more reference.