# Image upload with data without multipart/form-data

Tags: rest, http

I need to upload a file (method `POST` and `Content-Type: image/jpeg`) with some additionnal information (`folderId` and `userId`).

For some reason, on the client side, `multipart/form-data` is not an option

I thought of passing the `folderId` and `userId` in the HTTP headers and the image (`jpeg`) in the payload.

- Does this solution sound OK or is there any other/cleaner way to do ?
- Does it look correct and secure in a REST context ?

Note:

- Client side would be iOS
- No client js in the mean time. If there is a JS client, `folderId` and `userId` wont be given by the user through a form.

Comment: Usage of headers to send form data is not a good practice. How do you submit the form? do you use any javascript library for that?

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha I updated the post

Comment: You can send image as base64 if image is not too big

Comment: So you use native iOS url connection or something? Perhaps, this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460817/form-data-request-using-nsurlconnection-in-ios. HTTP headers should ideally be used for metadata & not for semantics. Also, depending on the server side network topology, such requests may be blocked/rewritten.

Comment: Hi @LaksithaRanasingha, could you tell a bit more about the difference between metadata and semantics? Thanks

Comment: For ex; Metadata - what content-type, size etc. Semantics - user data which matters to business operation the request does.